# How to change the number displayed when we press button

Tags: python, time, pygame, clock

I'm trying to make an clock that can count down the time, but I got stuck since I don't know how to change the number on the clock(for example when I press the "+ 1 minute" button the clock changes from 0:0 to 1:0), I'm new to python and python so I hope to get some information that I'll be able t understand.
This is my code btw:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,600))

GREEN 
YELLOW
BLACJ
RED
WHITE
KIARA

Text_1 = font_1.render('+',True,KIARA)
Text_2 = font_1.render('+',True,KIARA)
Text_3 = font_1.render('-',True,KIARA)
Text_4 = font_1.render('-',True,KIARA)
Text_5 = font_1.render('START',True,BLACK)
Text_6 = font_1.render('RESET',True,BLACK)

total_secs = 0
mins = int(total_secs/60)
secs = int(total_secs%60)
time = f"{mins}:{secs}"

Text_time = font_2.render(time,True,BLACK)
TextRect_time = Text_time.get_rect()
TextRect_time.center = (248,425)


running = True
while running:
    screen.fill(GREEN)

    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    screen.blit(Text_1,TextRect_1)
    screen.blit(Text_2,TextRect_2)
    screen.blit(Text_3,TextRect_3)
    screen.blit(Text_4,TextRect_4)
    screen.blit(Text_5,TextRect_5)
    screen.blit(Text_6,TextRect_6)
    screen.blit(Text_time,TextRect_time)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                if (70 < mouse_x < 130) and (70 < mouse_y < 130):

                if (170 < mouse_x < 230) and (70 < mouse_y < 130):

                if (70 < mouse_x < 130) and (220 < mouse_y < 280):

                if (170 < mouse_x < 230) and (220 < mouse_y < 280):

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You haven't declared any of those colors (GREEN, YELLOW etc.). Please include font_1 as well, otherwise it's difficult to reproduce this.

Comment: Your color names are not variables. BLACK = (0, 0, 0) ... would work since you assign an RGB value to the variable. At the end of your code you have tons of if-statements but there are no actions attached to them. ... if (condition) ... then do ... + you should use elif statements after the first if statement if you have more conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you press a key, you need to change the text and re-render the text surface. e.g.:

```py
if (70 < mouse_x < 130) and (70 < mouse_y < 130):
    mins = (mins+1) % 60
    time = f"{mins}:{secs}"
    Text_time = font_2.render(time, True, BLACK)
```